# For what is the move constructor and move assignment constructor in Unique Pointers needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I've got a simplified example of a `unique_ptr`. I wonder for what the move constructor and move assignment operator in the unique pointer is needed?
If I understand move constructors (and passing rvalues) right, these two lines of code should result the same.

```
UniquePointer<T> a(new T);
UniquePointer<T> a(UniquePointer<T>(new T));
```

And here is the simplified `UniquePointer` code:

```
template<typename T> class UniquePointer {
    T* m_ptr;
public:
    UniquePointer(const UniquePointer&) = delete;
    UniquePointer& operator=(const UniquePointer&) = delete;
    UniquePointer(UniquePointer&& rhs);
    UniquePointer& operator=(UniquePointer&& rhs);
    UniquePointer(T* ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) { }
    T* operator->() const { return m_ptr; }
    T& operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    T* get() const { return m_ptr; }
    ~UniquePointer() { delete m_ptr; }
};
```

Comment: For returning ownership: auto unique = std::make_unique<int>()

Comment: without supporting move semantics, you could not have it in a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First invokes the regular constructor `UniquePointer(T* ptr)` (not the move constructor). Second invokes the move constructor `UniquePointer(UniquePointer&& rhs)`, as you pass in a rvalue of the type `UniquePointer`, and the copy constructor is deleted.

You need the move constructor also when you do

```
UniquePtr<T> ptr = std::move(some_old_unique_ptr);
```

In this case you need to `std::move` from the old one, since the old one is a `lvalue`. The move assignment operator is invoked on already constructed objects

```
ptr = std::move(yet_another_ptr); // invokes the move assignment operator
```

As to why you need them, it is because of the design. Such objects are non-copyable, so you need to move them around.

Comment: If i understand you right it's needed to support the move operation of the standart library std:move() and has no other advantages?

Comment: @maniac you have to understand what move semantics mean. It allows you to "steal" the resource of the right hand side, and it is extremely useful when dealing with "expensive" to copy objects. In some cases you want to prevent copy (such as `unique_ptr`), so move is the only option. And yes, in that case, you need the move constructor and move assignment operator, as otherwise it will be impossible to pass your object around. Side note: `std::move` only performs a cast to a rvalue, does not move anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to transfer ownership from one scope to another, you need a separate object. And since you can't (and don't want to) copy a `unique_ptr`, that means you need to move it. For example, when returning a `unique_ptr` from a function.

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo);
    ...
    return ptr;
}
```

This requires either a move constructor or a copy constructor. Another common use case is initializing a class member from a constructor parameter.

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(std::unique_ptr<Foo> _foo_ptr)
       :foo_ptr(std::move(_foo_ptr))
    {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The move constructor and move assignment operator are needed for the [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as it is a non copy-able and therefore unique object.  Since it is non copy-able there needs to be a way to pass it to things and thus move operations take care of that.